# How to make API calls with App Access Token for retrieving relationship_status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, servlets, facebook-access-token, real-time-updates

I am working on a application development which is getting real updates from facebook, and I need to make API calls after getting a change notification. I am able to make API Calls using User Access Token but when I make a call with application access token to retrieve relationship status (or say any other files which requires access_token) of user (who had successfully permitted the application for those fields), I am getting null.
I am using Java servlets for the implementation of the same, App Access Token is working fine for subscriptions and even retrieving basic info and application info, but not specific information required. Kindly help me out for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating the auth token, have you got the following scope set;

```
user_relationships
```

You should then be able to see relationship status under /me

```
"relationship_status": "Engaged", 
"significant_other": {
    "name": "Jane Luu", 
    "id": "570340316"
 },
```

Comment: Thanks Pork for your valuable answer

but Is it applicable for application access_token too??? As I need to make API calls on basis of application by https://graph.facebook.com/ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=id,name,picture,relationship_status

while user with ID has provided access to application with permissions and at that time I had used SCOPE=user_relationships

so should I also add scope to auth_dialog "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+API_KEY+"&client_secret="+API_SECRET+"&grant_type=client_credentials"; ????

Comment: Thanks @Pork for your valuable answer but Is it applicable for application access_token too??? As I need to make API calls on basis of application by /ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN while user with ID has provided access to application with permissions and at that time(while providing permissions by user to the application) I had used SCOPE=user_relationships so should I also add scope to auth_dialog "scope=user_relationships" ????

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase the question. I've got a couple different versions of how to interpret it in my head and don't want to cause you pain if we aren't on the same page.

Comment: Hi @Pork, I tried to rephrase the question in next answer, Please tell me the way out... how to get the data required using app access_token upon change notification.

Comment: I am developing a web application which will get real-time updates from facebook regarding the change of relationship_status, location, email etc., 

So firstly I make users to authorize the application to access required information. For this I am specifying the "SCOPE=user_relationships" in URL for getting user access_token and able to get information(i.e. say relationship_status) with this user access_token. Now My application is added to user applications and My applications is able to access the information user allowed it for.

But after this one time authentication,

Comment: But after this one time authentication, I requested for App access_token by auth_dialog [graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+API_KEY+"&client_secret="+API_SECRET+"&grant_type=client_credentials]

I want to access users information via this app access_token, As My application is authorized by user to access this information, But In response of call to Graph API [~/ID?access_token=App_access_token&fields=id,name,picture,relationship_status] I am getting relationship_status=null which basic information(which doesn't require any access_token) is coming correctly.

Comment: I dont know why it is not getting current status of the user. I didnt get example of same type. Now I am stuck here, How to make such API call using app access_token.

Comment: Well I don't know about "real-time" but are you saying you have not been able to do a single graph api call so far?

Comment: Hi @Pork, I am able to do api calls, but when i am making calls with app access_token, I am not able to retrieve data which needed access_token(like location, relationship_status), only basic information is retrieved(like id, name, picture_url). While I am able to do same with user access_token.